# Router links and language changes

Tags: vuejs2

I have a list of router links of the form

```html
<router-link :to="'/' + $store.getters.lang" tag='v-btn' class="flat" active-class="active" exact>{{$t('home')}}</router-link>
<router-link :to="'/' + $store.getters.lang + '/pest'" tag='v-btn' class="flat">{{$t('factsheets')}}</router-link>
<router-link :to="'/' + $store.getters.lang + '/control'" tag='v-btn' class="flat" active-class="active">{{$t('control')}}</router-link>
```

which I want to re-format in the form of ...

```html
<router-link
     v-for="(item,key) in items"
     :key="key"
     @click=""
     :to="'/' + $store.getters.lang + item.path"
     tag='v-btn' class="flat" active-class="active" exact
****  v-html="item.title"> ****
     <!--$t('{{item.title}}')-->
</router-link>
```

My problem is at the **** line where the only way I can get the title of the link to display is via the v-html directive, but in doing so, I lose the ability to have that label change if the site's language option is subsequently switched (say, from EN to ES).

How can I integrate the $t(...) function into the v-for loop?

Comment: `v-bind` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-html="$t(item.title)"` should work, simple example:

```js
Vue.locale('en', {
  foo: 'foo 1',
  bar: 'bar 1',
  baz: 'baz 1'
})

Vue.locale('el', {
  foo: 'foo 2',
  bar: 'bar 2',
  baz: 'baz 2'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      items: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] //object name
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change() {
      let current = this.$lang.lang

      //toggle lang
      this.$lang.lang = (current === 'en') ? 'el' : 'en'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <button @click="change">change</button>

  <div v-for="item in items">
    <p v-html="$t(item)"></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

[Working JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t6aj3def/2/)